# How can I modify current page in Google extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to insert elements into the current page or just append, or even change color of a simple element. How can I do this from my google extension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use content scripts to inject a code into the currently loaded page.

This page would help you further.
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi

Answer (score 0):

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
               code: `  
// here add your js code

function changeBackgroundColor(selector,color){ 
    document.querySelector(selector)
      .style.backgroundColor= color;
}

  changeBackgroundColor('#id','red');
  console.log('done');
  `
  });


}, false);
```